# send fake email using mail clients

Tags: postfix

assume that, you have a pop3 email address saved on your outlook or other mail clients, if you changed your user information in account setting like the following attachment you can send any@any.com email.
my mail service is postfix and i set all the sender and recipient restriction such as reject_unlisted account or reject non fqdn domains or hostname but it's not worked! how you fix this problem in your enterprise mail services?
thanks

[image: how someone using my mail relay server to send arbitrary emails via any email address!]

Also this is all my configuration on main.cf :

```
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.11.5/README_FILES
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_mailbox_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
transport_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix_default.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_proxy_timeout = 3600s
disable_vrfy_command = yes
mynetworks = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk-pop/poplock
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain,reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch,reject_known_sender_login_mismatch,hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_client_access, pcre:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/non_auth.re, check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_relay_restrictions =permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination, reject_unlisted_sender
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain,reject_non_fqdn_sender,permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unauth_destination, defer_unauth_destination,reject_unverified_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_uid_maps = static:30
virtual_gid_maps = static:31
smtpd_milters = , inet:127.0.0.1:12768
non_smtpd_milters =
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/sdd_transport_maps
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
plesk_virtual_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mailbox_size_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
myhostname = host.com
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
smtpd_tls_protocols = TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
tls_medium_cipherlist = HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
message_size_limit = 102400000
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = no
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

but the problem is until exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender` PostFix configuration directive, which is [documented here](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender).

Note that I'd also make sure to log this and get the person who does this fired immediately (unless it's a typo, of course).